# get current url odoo from javascript

Tags: javascript, session, url, controller, odoo-8

what's wrong with my code, I want to get current url from JavaScript and I keep all url in session:

controller.py:

```
class MyController(http.Controller): 
    @http.route(['/action_set_current_url/<string:url>'], type='json', auth="public")
    def set_current_url(self, url, **post):
     request.session['my_current_url'] = url
     return {"my_current_url":my_current_url}
```

i call this function on JavaScript code:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(e){
       var url=window.location.href 
       openerp.jsonRpc("/action_set_current_url/", 'call',url)
});
```

and i want to get it in my model using:

```
current_url = http.request.session.get('my_current_url')
```

but i got nothing!! 
thanks

Comment: You have to use ajax in your js file. For that you can take reference from "Stripe Payment Acquirer" module.

Comment: can i have a n example beacause i check "stripe payment acquirer" code and i dont know where is js file

Comment: i want to have an complete url like this: http://10.10.20.1:8069/web#id=51&view_type=form&model=stock.picking&action=181&active_id=3 when i click a button and send it to mail, thanks

Comment: In that module you get your js code under static/src/js and from controller/main you get your json type controller and after that in payment.py under models you can able to get your url